# Перемешиваются view при скроллинге в listview

Tags: java, android

Все те же таймеры. Кнопка Стоп и Старт.

При загрузке в первый раз, все нормально, таймеры тикают, после поворота экрана и скроллинга значения элементов меняются местами или пропадают.

Я не уверен на счет правильности действий, но что бы отображать счет таймера, я передаю в его модель объект ViewHolder'a по нажатию на кнопку Старт.

Фрагмент кода модели:

```
 private String name;
 private  Boolean isStart=false;
 private  Long elapsedTime=0L,seconds=0L,hours=0L,minutes=0L,lastPause=0L,updateTime=0L,startTime=0L,days=0L;
private Runnable updateTimeThread=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(isStart && startTime!=0) {
            updateTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + lastPause);
            seconds = updateTime / 1000;
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            hours = minutes / 60;

            seconds = seconds % 60;
            minutes = minutes % 60;
            hours = hours % 24;

            holder.days.setText(String.format("%04d", days));
            holder.hours.setText(String.format("%02d", hours));
            holder.minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
            holder.seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));
            Log.d("myTag",name+" "+seconds);
            MainActivity.handler.post(this);
        }
    }
};
MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder;

public MyAdapter.ViewHolder getHolder() {
    return holder;
}

public void setHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
}

public Runnable getRunnable() {
    return updateTimeThread;
}
```

Фрагмент кода адаптера:

```
 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
    final Runnable updateTimeThread=tracker.getRunnable();


    View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(row == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
        holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
        holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
        holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
        holder.start = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        holder.stop = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
        holder.start.setEnabled(true);
        holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
        holder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;



    if(tracker.getIsStart()){
        holder.start.setEnabled(false);
        holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
    }


     onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getId()) {
                 case R.id.btStart:
                     tracker.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                     tracker.setIsStart(true);
                     tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
                     MainActivity.handler.post(updateTimeThread);
                     finalHolder.start.setEnabled(false);
                     finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(true);
                     break;
                 case R.id.btStop:
                     tracker.setLastPause(tracker.getUpdateTime());
                     MainActivity.handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeThread);
                     finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                     finalHolder.start.setEnabled(true);
                     tracker.setIsStart(false);
                     break;
             }
         }
     };
    holder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    holder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView  name,days,hours,minutes,seconds;
    Button start,stop;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Проблема решилась для адаптера ArrayAdapter добавлением методов, элементы больше не перемешиваются и все работает хорошо, я вставил эти методы в SimpleCursorAdapter(в связке с LoaderCallback), который можно сказать брат близнец ArrayAdapter, но там это не работало, да элементы больше не перемешиваются, но они пропадают при прокрутке. So close(

```
  @Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   if(getCount()==0)
      return super.getViewTypeCount();
    else
      return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вот эту замечательную [ссылку](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/06/tips-for-listview-view-recycling-use.html) которая посоветовала изменить layout-params у listview с wrap_content на fill_parent и все заработало, конечно еще я оставил те 2 метода которые в **update**.